# How to get the values from the same class in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to get the values from the same class in jquery?

```
<div class="wider-box google-map-wrapper">
    <h3 class="touch-line uc">Product tags</h3>
    <div class="wider-box content-block profile-tags">
        <p>
            <a href="/directory/product/electronic_goods/">Electronic Goods</a>
            <a href="/directory/product/home_appliances/">Home Appliances</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3 class="touch-line uc">Brand tags </h3>
    <div class="wider-box content-block profile-tags">
        <p>
            <a href="/directory/brand/apple/">Apple</a>
            <a href="/directory/brand/breville/">Breville</a>

            <a href="/directory/brand/de_longhi/">De Longhi</a>

            <a href="/directory/brand/dyson/">Dyson</a>

            <a href="/directory/brand/kenwood/">Kenwood</a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

I need the data in in the href.It has to be

```
Electronic Goods | Home Appliances
```

and

```
Apple | Breville | De Longhi | Dyson | Kenwood.
```

Both should be in different.

Comment: don't have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Using map():

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PqxRR/)

```
var str = $('a').map(function(){
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML)
}).get().join(' | ');
```

Remove join() to get an array.

Comment: I think he want two string. One with the 'products' and another one with the 'brands'.

Comment: @FelipeFonseca didn't saw that, thx. So just use more specific selector for each loop (map). If OP is not too lazy, he should be able to adapt code i guess

Answer (score 0):

Try using each function and get the text of `<a>`

```
$('div.profile-tags a').each(function(){

   var allTexts=[];

    allTexts.push($(this).text());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add some class to your anhour  tag, then you can have it in different object

```
 menu1 for all menu 1s
 <a class='menu1' href="/directory/product/electronic_goods/">Electronic Goods</a>


 menu2 for all menu 2s

<a class='menu2' href="/directory/brand/apple/">Apple</a>
```

see the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/PqxRR/1/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var all_list=[];
$('div.profile-tags').each(function(){
    var text_list = []
    $(this).find('a').each(function(){
        text_list.push($(this).text());
    })
    all_list.push(text_list);
});
console.log(all_list[0].join('|'));
console.log(all_list[1].join('|'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Appended to @A. Wolff answer, if you want to alert both classes anchor text separately use following :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".wider-box" ).each(function() {
        var str = $(this).find("a").map(function(){
            return $.trim(this.innerHTML)
        }).get().join(' | ');
    alert(str);
    });
});
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/PqxRR/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
var data = [];
$('.wider-box p').each(function () {
    data.push($(this).children().map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get());
});
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/59FXP/.